# Are these two functions equivalent?

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

I checked several cases and saw that two functions are equivalent in these samples.
However, are the two equivalent in all cases?
Is there a way to check that?

**Explicit function:**

```
  g[x_]= π
  h[_] = π
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.

`_` is a pattern that matches any expression.

`x_` is the same thing, with a name, `x`.  The pattern name can be used in two ways.

The most common way is to refer to it on the right hand side of the definition or rule.  For example, `f[x_] := x^2`.  If we are not using the matched expression in the right hand side, there's no reason to name the pattern.

The other situation is when two sub-patterns have the same name.  This is used to require them to match the same expression.  For example, `{x_, x_}` matches `{1,1}` but not `{1,2}`.  In contrast, `{_, _}` matches both `{1,1}` and `{1,2}`.

Neither situation applies to your example.  The pattern name is never used for anything.  Thus there's no purpose of naming the pattern.

Further reading:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I've just known that the pattern is called blank.